# Selectpicker not working with form repeater

Tags: javascript, jquery

I’m using the following plugn https://www.jqueryscript.net/form/jQuery-Plugin-For-Dynamic-Form-Field-Generator-DuplicateElement.html to duplicate some fields, but when I try to use selectpicker then I’m not bale to select any optioon from the duplicated dropdown menu, here is a codepen fiddle https://codepen.io/vince84vecchio/pen/ZdYQPO to show you what the problem is.

this is the code:

```
    $(function () {



        $('#additional-field-model').duplicateElement({

            "class_remove": ".remove-this-field",
            "class_create": ".create-new-field"
        });

                    // Call and initiate selectpicker plugin
                $('.bs-select').selectpicker({
                    iconBase: 'fa',
                    tickIcon: 'fa-check',
                    // Prevent dropdown to show on top
                    dropupAuto: false
                });

        // refresh selectpicker so it does load dropdown on each duplicated field
        $('#kmg_admin_new_building_type').selectpicker('refresh');


    });
```

Comment: I saw your code and i think its because of your id attribute kmg_admin_new_building_type
Because in html duplicate id on same page cause issue

Answer (score 1):

Start with a hidden `<select>` field where you have **not** initialized selectpicker using `.selectpicker()`.

To get the first row (and subsequent rows) duplicate the hidden element, show it using `.show()` and finally initialize it using `.selectpicker()`.